# How to get: Hints, Go to Definition, Peek, etc. from tsx, jsx source files to Node_modules Bootstrap styles files (ccs, scss, less) with VS Cod

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, webpack, next.js

This is about a Next Framework from React project installed with npm Create-next-app template and Bootstrap npm package.

I tested several Vs code extensions and only get to jump to /styles/global.ccs and /styles/*.modules.css files, but didn’t to /node_modules/… bootstrap styles files (css, scss, less).
At the browser preview page styles work fine, including  Node_modules Bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got that VsCode displays the npm bootstrap css class definitions from  my tsx file.
I imported npm bootstrap css in globals.css file. I using CSS Navigation VsCode plugin.
Code line added in /styles/global.css:

```
@import "~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```